# Bootstrap 4: Small floating icon menu

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've looked around on the internet and can't find what I want. I need to make a small Sidebar menu that sticks to the left side and is centered.

The only thing that I found was this:

```
`https://codepen.io/kemsly/pen/mJxwJg`
```

but its use too much js.

If you know any links or guides that I can follow, please don't hesitate to post them here, I would appreciate it so much.

Kind Regards,
Faziki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

- sticking to left side: **position:fixed**
- centered... take **50% of the view height** and then deduct **half the height of your sidebar div**

**working snippet** below:

```css
.floatingLeft {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50vh - 67px);
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='floatingLeft'>
  <div class='icon blue'>
    <h4 class='photoshop'>Photoshop</h4>
  </div>
  <div class='icon purple'>
    <h4 class='aftereffects'>AfterEffects</h4>
  </div>
  <div class='icon green'>
    <h4 class='dreamweaver'>DreamWeaver</h4>
  </div>
  <div class='icon red'>
    <h4 class='flash'>Flash</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. Porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet.
  Id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique. Donec massa sapien
  faucibus et molestie ac. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio.</p>

<p>Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Nec nam aliquam sem et. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Ac feugiat
  sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed. Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis
  lectus nulla at. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis.</p>

<p>Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Sem et tortor consequat id porta. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida. Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla
  facilisi. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Dui sapien eget mi proin sed
  libero enim sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit. Enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.</p>

<p>Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque.
  Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. At augue eget arcu dictum varius. Vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut
  tristique et egestas quis ipsum.</p>

<p>Aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris
  nunc. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit
  libero volutpat. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.</p>

<p>Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit
  dignissim sodales ut eu. Nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec
  feugiat in. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. Volutpat sed cras ornare arcu.</p>

<p>Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Aenean et tortor at risus. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Mi
  bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Id leo in vitae turpis. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa
  id neque aliquam vestibulum. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan.</p>

<p>Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Convallis posuere morbi
  leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam. Quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue. Nam at lectus urna duis. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis.</p>

<p>Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis. Viverra justo
  nec ultrices dui. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Lorem sed risus ultricies
  tristique nulla aliquet enim. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus
  laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed.</p>

<p>Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. In massa tempor nec feugiat. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan
  sit amet nulla facilisi. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque.
  Diam maecenas sed enim ut.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Dictumst
  quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Dui faucibus in ornare
  quam viverra. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque.</p>

<p>Velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim
  suspendisse in. Auctor urna nunc id cursus metus. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus
  purus in. Sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed.</p>
```